# Frontend en Visual Studio y C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, backend, diseño, frontend

Quisiera tener su consejo para poder guiarme sobre mi duda. Estudié programación en C#, utilizando visual studio. Nos enfocamos mucho en el Backend, pero a la hora de diseñar los sitios, me quedo muy corto, no logro un "look profesional" por eso me gustaría que me aconsejaran que hacer al respecto, si suelen programarlo en HTTP, CSS y Java o si utilizan alguna otra herramienta que les permita diseñar paginas atractivas y que tengan un buen back en c#.

Agradezco su guía y consejos sobre este tema.
Saludos!

Comment: Preguntas así, están basadas en opiniones, por lo tanto, son cerradas. Que tengas 20 puntos y entra a la sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol ahí se puede conversar de estos temas libremente. Por otro lado, te sugiero que aprendas HTML, CSS y Javascript, frameworks de CSS como Bootstrap, Material Design. El detalle no es tanto la herramienta o IDE al que te refieres, es más orientado al dominio de CSS, efectos, transiciones. Revisa cursos de UI/UX para programadores. Saludos.